# AWK: Minus variable, when variable is a negative number

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to subtract the variable from the first column of a file. 
I have awk command:

```
awk -v start=$start '{print $1-$start}' < file_1 > file_2
```

which works if $start is a positive number, but gives an error if it is a negative.

Any idea?

Comment: What values of `$1`, `start` did you try this?

Comment: Try surrounding `$start` with parentheses.

Comment: The awk variable is named `start`. `$start` is the value of input field number `start` and you can't use a negative field number.

Comment: `which works if $start is a positive number` - no, it doesn't, look at your results again.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on this.

```
start="Your_shell_values"
awk -v start="$start" '{print $1-start}' file_1 > file_2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am stupid :)